# strange timestamp and timedelta formats - how to convert them?

Tags: django, django-timezone

I am using external api which returns dates (as strings) in a strange format:

```
2012-09-26T15:44:10.376000 #timestamp
0:00:01.714000 #delta (some time duration)
```

I want to convert them to this format:

```
19 Sep 2012 17:02
0:17:34
```

Is there easy way to do this?
I can convert them in my `view` or in `template`

edit -----------------------------------------------------------

I found solution for timestamp:

```
date_str = '2012-09-26T15:44:10.376000'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
str = date.strftime('%m %b %Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: That's not a strange format at all... it's ISO-8601. What have you already tried for string conversion?

Comment: nothing - I just started python and django - still looking for solution

Comment: Well what research did you do? I just typed "format date and time in python" and got a bunch of interesting results.

Comment: What do you want to convert the delta into? Its already a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) and then:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2012-09-26T15:44:10.376000')
>>> dt.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M')
'26 Sep 2012 15:44'
```

For django, you can pass the `dt` object to your template and use the [`date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date):

```
{{ dt|date:"d b Y H:M" }}
```

Comment: I found also django date parser: `from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime`. In the date filter you have to skip `%` signs. Thanks